# Creating instances from strings over different namespaces and different assemblies

Tags: c#, xml, reflection, object, components

I am making a component based system (each object delegates all functionality to a variety of components which can be added at runtime) and want to be able to define my objects in XML files for ease. I know how to use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create my objects from strings, but I require full classnames and assembly names.

The issue comes from the fact that these components may be either pre-built in my library (say assembly `FirstAssembly.dll` and namespace `Foo.Bar`) or defined specifically for my game (say assembly `SecondAssembly.dll` and namespace `Second.Blah`).

```
//In some assembly FirstAssembly.dll

namespace Foo.Bar
{
class SomeClassA
{
}

class SomeClassB
{
}
}

//In some assembly SecondAssembly.dll

namespace Second.Blah
{
class SomeClassC
{
}

class SomeClassD
{
}
}

//In my XML..I would much prefer
<class="SomeClassA"...> </class>
<class="SomeClassD"...> </class>

//Over this, which would just need to check FirstAssembly and SecondAssembly and error handle
<class="Foo.Bar.SomeClassB"...></class>
<class="Second.Blah.SomeClassD"...></class>

//Which I would much prefer over
<class="Foo.Bar.SomeClassB" assembly="FirstAssembly"...></class>
<class="Second.Blah.SomeClassD" assembly="SecondAssembly"...></class>
```

The last solution would be easy, if rather annoying - I need assembly names, or at least some way of saying 'component from library' or 'component from game'.

The second solution is probably easier - I just need (some way) of checking - probably just `try/catch` - if the class is in FirstAssembly; if not, try SecondAssembly.

The first solution is what I really want to do, but I do not think it possible. The amount of namespaces would make it difficult.

tl;dr Is there a way I can make this system work so my XML files look as close to the first solution as possible? If not, is the second solution viable?

Comment: did you take a look at MEF or Unity ?

Comment: @Steve B Do you mean to use as my library, or for this part? If the former..I want to write it myself, mostly for learning. If the latter, I shall look.

Comment: it was the former. Challenging to write yourself such fonctionnalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
Type targetType = (from assembly in candidateAssemblies
                   from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                   where type.Name == nameFromXml
                   select type).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that:

- If there are multiple matches, this will just return the first one.
- If there are *no* matches, this will return `null`
- You may wish to add extra conditions, such as public types etc

Comment: I assume candidateAssemblies is a list of the assemblies..I shall give this a test but it looks exactly like what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @The Communist Duck: Types declared as public :) For example, you may not want internal types, or types which only have internal constructors etc to be found.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that :P Probably isn't aided by my naive approach of just declaring (close to) everything as a public class/interface/struct.